# How to hide records when the date has passed?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

I am unsure on how to check whether a date has passed in order to only show rows where the date has not passed.

I am using CodeIgniter and when the date is set, I'm not using a date type (using varchar) in the MySQL table as I'm using the jQuery date-picker to set the date.

So when the date is set, I need to pull the date from the table to check whether the date has passed or not?

So I'm  not sure whether I have to totally change my date input to use the date type in the MySql table in order to pull the date and check whether it is < now()

Any guidance or advice would be extremely appreciated :)

Comment: Can you supply some sample data? What format are your dates in (eg yyyy-MM-dd etc)?

Comment: the jQuery datepicker does mm/dd/yyyy but ideally I need it to be dd/mm/yyyy. I have changed the dateFormat in the JS, but isn't working for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason for NOT using the date type in MySQL? If is a date, why not store it as a date? It will still be usable as a string in your PHP script when you retrieve it from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use the date type in MySQL if you are tracking dates, that way you have all the [date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) available to you.  The date functions of MySQL are much faster than trying to parse them as text with PHP.